# How to set an URI from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

I have seen several examples like

[How to Set Image Resource URI from Code-Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022707/how-to-set-image-resource-uri-from-code-behind)

but haven't understood.

If I have the following solution

[image]

[image]

I want to set the uri for ita.png

```
 Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(?????)).Stream;
  notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pack URI syntax described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx)

In your case it would be something like this:

```
  Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/ITA.png")).Stream;
  notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```