# Access component in c# like in xaml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

In XAML, you can access the project resources with

```
/Namespace;Component/exemple.png
```

for exemple :

```
<Image Source="/Test;Component/dessin.png"/>
```

I want to know if I can do something like that in c# ?

(I make a WPF app in visual studio 2017)

**EDIT**

I can find this uri "pack://application:,,,/Test;component/dessin.png" but i need the file path "D:...."

Comment: Something similar can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022707/how-to-set-image-resource-uri-from-code-behind

Comment: It's not really what I want, I want a file path, not a uri